# Eclipse RCP - invalid view IDs in workbench.xml

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

We're developing an Eclipse RCP (still **3.7**) application. In the `workbench.xml` are stored IDs of views that are currently visible in the various perspectives (depending on the user settings).

A problem arised when we renamed the IDs of some of these views in the respective `plugin.xml` files. Upon startup, the workbench tries to restore states of the perspectives, but because the views have different IDs than in the previous run of the app, an error dialog appears upon opening of each perspetive:

[image]

This dialog is shown automatically from the Eclipse framework method `org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.setPerspective()`, so we cannot control its appearing anyhow. Moreover, the given perspectives are thereafter empty.

The user has to use the menu command `Views > Reset` to return into a consistent state (default, however). This has to be done manually in each of the perspectives, which is very tedious. We definitely want to avoid to force our users to do this every time we change a view ID in a new version of the app (both the error dialog and using the Reset command).

The question is, how should such situation be solved?

1. Validate the contents (the memento) of the `workbench.xml` before the workbench is restored. Compare the list of views in it with actual existing views in `ViewRegistry`. In case of difference, clear the memento completely. However, this clears all the other various settings stored in the `workbench.xml` as well.
2. Manually update the contents of the `workbench.xml`: Before the workbench is restored, open the file and manually replace all the obsolete IDs with their new values. This requires us to manually provide such "migration script" for every newly released app version that introduces such changes.

Any other (better) ideas?

Comment: Why not change the view ids back to what they were?

Comment: There generally can be some implementation changes that require their renaming. Or, which is more probable, we might want to completely remove a view from a perspective. Or a user can remove a plugin from his installation.